# shell script to check status of another script and restart it

Tags: php, shell

I would like to have a shell scipt that runs infinitely and keeps checking status of a php script (say my.php) and restarts it if the script has terminated somehow. I have the idea to go for -

```
ps -aux | grep "my.php"
```

and then use the result of this to check the status and do accordingly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your system has `pgrep`, it's a whole lot easier to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply say:

```
ps -aux | grep -q "my.php" || php -f my.php
```

The way it works is that `grep -q` will not output anything but will return an "OK" exit code if it found something. when it returns a "NOT OK" exit code, the part after the `||` ("or") gets executed (because of boolean short-circuit evaluation - look it up).

You also need to make sure that:

1. you run the new script in the background and detach it from your console so that your script can keep monitoring
2. when you run `ps | grep` sometimes ps also lists your grep and then the grep "greps itself", so you have to filter that out.

It should look something like this:

```
while true
    ps -aux | grep -v grep | grep -q "my.php" || ( nohup php -f "my.php" & )
    sleep 1
done
```

or some-such..

Comment: "T" means that someone sent it a -STOP signal - this usually happens on purpose: the script was suspended in the background, or is being debugged. You don't want to go and start a second process when that happens, because the script is liable to continue in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is, start your php-program in a loop:

```
for ((;;))
do
   my.php 
done
```

With Linux ps, you could use

```
ps -C "my.php"
```

instead of grep, to identify my.php. Grep commands often find themselves. Maybe your ps has a similar switch?

Comment: I don't know what operating system you're using, but in mine, -C is *"Change the way the CPU percentage is calculated by using a "raw" CPU calculation that ignores "resident" time"*.  If the OP's question is about PHP and Shell, answer the question from the perspective of PHP and shell, not your particular flavour of some other command.

Comment: I'm using Linux, and the manpage of ps says `This ps conforms to:
1) Version 2 of the Single Unix Specification, 2) The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 6, 3) IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition, 4) X/Open System Interfaces Extension [UP XSI], 5) ISO/IEC 9945:2003` - I thought that's enough.

Comment: All we know from the question is that the OP's operating system uses Berkeley-style options for `ps` rather than SystemV options.

Comment: You're right. I deemphasized the Linux style ps-part, and concentrate more on the bash-part. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you DO really feel the need to grep the output of `ps`, beware of your grep finding itself.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sleep 60 &
[1] 66677
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ps aux | grep sleep
ghoti      66677   0.0  0.0   3928    784  11  S     4:11PM     0:00.00 sleep 60
ghoti      66681   0.0  0.0  16440   1348  11  S+    4:12PM     0:00.00 grep sleep
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

There's an easy way to avoid this.  Just make part of your grep into a more complex regular expression.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sleep 60 &
[2] 66717
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ps aux | grep '[s]leep'
ghoti      66677   0.0  0.0   3928    784  11  S     4:11PM     0:00.00 sleep 60
ghoti      66717   0.0  0.0   3928    784  11  S     4:13PM     0:00.00 sleep 60
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

On the other hand, if you just want to make sure that your PHP script always runs, you can wrap it in something that re-runs it when it dies:

```
while true; do
  php /path/to/my.php
done
```

If you want this to run at startup, you can edit your crontab on the server, and use a @reboot tag, assuming you're using "Vixie" cron (common on Linux and BSD):

```
@reboot /path/to/wrapperscript
```

You can **`man crontab`** and **`man 5 crontab`** for more details on how to use cron and the `@reboot` tag.